# How to use machine learning in earth engine applications?

Tags: google-earth-engine-javascript-api, google-earth-engine-python-api

I have developed a earth engine web application for my phd research. However, I can't figure out how to add the results of the machine learning techniques in the app directly without using any paid version of the API. I am a student and I am looking for a workaround instead of investing money and using the paid APIs for this task. I want to integrate the earth engine web application that currently shows the data I am working with. To add the machine learning results, I see two solutions:

1. I could convert the earth engine web application to python using geemap API
2. or I could use python APIs in earthengine platform which currently seem to be paid versions.

If anyone has any other solutions. Please share as I have not integrated the earthengine code directly with any python libraries. I have always downloaded the data and used it as an input to my model in a python platform. The results are then shown in a GIS software. So to create a web application that does this in one single step is a bit complicated.

I tried using [geemap](https://geemap.org/) but it didn't work out as I have huge chunk of code that is in javascript and it kept giving errors when I tried to convert it to python language. Next, I tried using machine learning [APIs](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/guides/machine-learning#:%7E:text=Machine%20Learning%20(ML)%20is%20a,into%20two%20or%20more%20categories.) but they may require payment for both commercial and non-commercial use.

Comment: - what do you mean by "add the results of the machine learning techniques in the app" ? 
- why do you need a public web app ? (that maybe what forces you to use the paid version of GEE) 
- I have never faced any issues converting Javascript to Python API so you'll need to show more code example if you want us to help you